# Yureka Plus stuck on "Preparing to start.. Starting Apps" screen after flashing crDroid 6.0.1

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, cyanogenmod, custom-rom

I had rooted my Yu Yureka plus by unlocking the bootloader using adb fastboot method, then flashing the TWRP recovery V2.8.7.0, and then flashing superSU v2.46.

After rebooting my yureka plus, and going to recovery it started cynogen recovery only, even though update cynogen recovery option was disabled.
So I flashed TWRP again and without rebooting again, just flashed crDroidAndroid-6.0.1-20160827-tomato.zip and GApps zip file from internal memory. The phone rebooted and worked fine after that.

But while playing a game the phone automatically rebooted and ever since have been stuck on "Preparing to start.. Starting apps.."

I had disabled the developer options because I thought it was working fine. 
The phone is working behind the preparing to start screen.. I can hear the message notification and caller ringtone when someone messages or calls, but can't access anything

Any suggestions what I should do now?

I have tried doing a factory reset from recovery but the problem persists and none of the hardware buttons are working, had to remove battery to access the recovery (still cyanogen recovery is opening).

Please HELP!

Answer (score 0):

you can us this tutorial to get back to stock rom

http://www.thetechnotriad.com/393/how-to-unbrick-yu-yureka/

Comment: After following the steps from this page my phone got hard bricked, even though I used the flashing tools for cm12 (YuPlayGod's github page) and not the one provided on that page. No idea why. So after searching on google and youtube I came across this: https://androidmtk.com/download-yu-stock-rom-for-all-models

Comment: I followed the steps and now KitKat is running except launcher is not working, instead play store open every time I try to go to home screen. So tried the nova launcher but that still doesn't work with home screen, have to open through playstore, every time. But rest is working.

Comment: So now you're running on stock KitKat arent you? Why don't you do the OTA updates? BTW the link worked perfectly for me.

Comment: Yeah, its stock kitkat. though no idea why the link didn't work for me..